# Overall Code Coverage with AppExchange app installed

Tags: apex, unit-test

We have an accounting app customized from AppExchange called Accounting Books.  When I go to the development console, I get such low overall code coverage, because of their app.  When I try to write a simple trigger or class, I have hard time passing the code because of these.  How can I fix them?

There are all the triggers and test classes from AccountingBooks app

[image]

Comment: If unmanaged then you will have to write/modify the test cases to increase code coverage. If managed, it does not count against your code coverage so the issue is related to your classes and you can ignore the managed classes

Comment: @Eric your comment really should be an answer.

Comment: @ca_peterson - done. I did not think it had enough substance to be an answer so I posted as comment hoping OP would clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If unmanaged then you will have to write/modify the test cases to increase code coverage. If managed, it does not count against your code coverage so the issue is related to your classes and you can ignore the managed classes